# Retrieve primary key column definition of a generic entity in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Let say I have a generic method using JPA to list out entities

```
    public <T> List<T> list(Class<T> entity) throws Exception {

        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery( entity );
        Root<T> root = query.from( entity );

        query.select( root );

        //possible?
        query.orderBy(builder.asc(...));

        result = em.createQuery( query ).getResultList();

        return result;
   }
```

Is there anyway for us to add `orderby` to the query and make it order by the primary key without specify the primary column as the expression? I mean, is there a `Key`/`Constant` or something in JPA meaning a primary key column of any entity, or a util method to retrieve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This information is available via [metamodel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/package-summary.html). Something as follows should work in case of singular id attribute (not tested, so likely some problems, especially with generics, but approach in general is this):

```
public <T> SingularAttribute<? super T, ?> getIdAttribute(EntityManager em, 
                                                          Class<T> clazz) {
    Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
    IdentifiableType<T> of = (IdentifiableType<T>) m.managedType(clazz);
    return of.getId(of.getIdType().getJavaType());
}

//usage
SingularAttribute idAttribute = getIdAttribute(em, entity);
Path<?> pathToId = root.get(idAttribute);
query.orderBy(builder.asc(pathToId));
```

When entities that use [IdClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html) should also be supported, solution is bit more complex, but possible with methods provided by [IdentifiableType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/IdentifiableType.html).